# Find derivative of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 +2}}$ using definition

Tags: calculus

I recognise that the derivative of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 +2}}$ is given by the expression $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{x+h}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2}+2}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 +2}}}{h}$. But I have trouble proceeding from here. Any kind soul, please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have $$\frac{1}{h}\frac{(x+h)\sqrt{x^2+2}-x\sqrt{(x+h)^2+2}}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2+2}\,\sqrt{x^2+2}}$$
and now multiply numerator and denominator by $$(x+h)\sqrt{(x^2+2)}+x\sqrt{((x+h)^2+2)}$$
can you proceed?

Comment: Thank you, You are brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps :

- put everything on the same denominator
- you should have a numerator equal to something like $A-B$, where $A$ and $B$ have roots you don't want to see. Multiply both numerator and denominator by $A+B$ (of which limit in $x$ is non null)
- once you have done this, you should be able to see the limit (if not, factorize or multiply by some power of $h$ to see it)

good luck